# How use setEnv with another Env?

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, setenv, env

My question is how can I use setEnv with an already defined environment variable.

For example:

"/etc/apache2/envvars"

```
...
export SSL_ROOT_DIR=/etc/letsencrypt/live
export DEFAULT_HOME_DIR=/var/www/html
...
```

"/etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.tld.conf"

```
...
SetEnv SERVERNAME domain.tld
SetEnv HOME_DIR ${DEFAULT_HOME_DIR}/${SERVERNAME}
SetEnv LOG_DIR ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/${SERVERNAME}
SetEnv SSL_DIR ${SSL_ROOT_DIR}/${SERVERNAME}
...
DocumentRoot ${HOME_DIR}
<Directory "${HOME_DIR}">
  ...
</Directory>
...
SSLCertificateFile ${SSL_DIR}/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile ${SSL_DIR}/privkey.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile ${SSL_DIR}/chain.pem
...
```

Without env this config work!

Error output

```
[core:warn] [pid 13844] AH00111: Config variable ${SERVERNAME} is not defined
[core:warn] [pid 13844] AH00111: Config variable ${SERVERNAME} is not defined
[core:warn] [pid 13844] AH00111: Config variable ${SERVERNAME} is not defined
[core:warn] [pid 13844] AH00111: Config variable ${SERVERNAME} is not defined
[core:warn] [pid 13844] AH00111: Config variable ${HOME_DIR} is not defined
[core:warn] [pid 13844] AH00111: Config variable ${HOME_DIR} is not defined
[core:warn] [pid 13844] AH00111: Config variable ${LOG_DIR} is not defined
[core:warn] [pid 13844] AH00111: Config variable ${LOG_DIR} is not defined
[core:warn] [pid 13844] AH00111: Config variable ${SSL_DIR} is not defined
[core:warn] [pid 13844] AH00111: Config variable ${SSL_DIR} is not defined
[core:warn] [pid 13844] AH00111: Config variable ${SSL_DIR} is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a conceptual misunderstanding about how these work in Apache, but it's not your fault. It's very misleading in Apache and a very common misunderstanding.

Background:

There are two types of environment variables in Apache, native process-wide environment variables and per-request environment variables (that will become the former for a CGI if a CGI happens to be run)

The confusion:

- Variables of the form ${FOO} are interpolated at **startup**, they can
  only be native environment variables (commonly sourced from
  bin/envvars before apachectl/httpd are ever run)
- Directives like SetEnv and SetEnvIf set per-request environment variables. Even when they appear unconditional, they aren't executed until request-processing and don't set native environment variables.